# Does angular UI router require the key names used in resolve to be unique across all states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) for resolve doesn't specify if there are any gotcha regarding the choice of key name.

So if I have code like the following will the controllers get the same promise or the correct one?

```
...
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   controller: 'ControllerA',
   resolve:{
     promiseObj:  function($http) {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});
     }
   }
}).state('otherState', {
   controller: 'ControllerB',
   resolve: {
     promiseObj: function($http) {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someOtherUrl'});
     }
   }
});


...
.controller('ControllerA', ['promiseObj', function(promiseObj) {...}])
.controller('ControllerB', ['promiseObj', function(promiseObj) {...}])
```

Comment: This is fine - http://plnkr.co/edit/6wEWVC?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolves names can be re-used (with caution, of course).  They can even be overridden in a child resolve.  The child resolve can even depend on the parent resolve.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   controller: 'ControllerA',
   resolve:{
     promiseObj:  function($http) {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});
     }
   }
}).state('otherState', {
   controller: 'myState.Child',
   resolve: {
     promiseObj: function($http, promiseObj) { // the parent resolve data is injected as promiseObj
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someOtherUrl'});
     }
   }
});
```